# Options in GUI for custom Weka classifier

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka

I've implemented my own custom classifier for Weka, which inherits from Classifier and implements Serializable and also OptionHandler.

At the moment i've been able to run the classifier from the Weka UI perfectly, but without parameters. I know that i need to implement the following methods in order to see the options in the UI:

```
public void setOptions(String [] options) throws Exception
public String [] getOptions()
public Enumeration listOptions()
```

I've implemented getOptions with some dummy code and it's being perfectly called by the UI (I used a System.out.println to log this). And I also implemented a dummy code for listOptions but it's never being called.

When I try to select the options for my algorithm by the UI i only see the "Debug" option. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem and see my options by the UI?

Basically the thing that i want to do is to run my algorithm from Weka but using custom options/parameters.

I've read this document but i think it's not very useful:

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Writing+your+own+Classifier+(post+3.5.2)

Do you have any idea or example to solve this?

Comment: For Weka questions, it's best to ask at the Weka list, where you usually get a fast reply by the main authors of Weka.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I realized by chance :) that if I use the get and set methods instead of just accessing the attributes it works!

More clearly, for an attribute named "threshold" represented by "T" as an option:

This code doesn't work:

```
public String[] getOptions() {

    String[] options = new String[3];
    int current = 0;
    options[current++] = "-T";
    options[current++] = "" + threshold;

    while (current < options.length) {
        options[current++] = "";
    }
    return options;
}
```

And this code works:

```
public String[] getOptions() {

    String[] options = new String[3];
    int current = 0;
    options[current++] = "-T";
    options[current++] = "" + getThreshold();

    while (current < options.length) {
        options[current++] = "";
    }
    return options;
}
```

The same for setOptions(String[] options) method.

You only need to use the accessors.